# tlmgr install : package translator not present in repository

Tags: color, colortbl, threeparttable, tlmgr

To reduce the size of docker image I have to install  the following `latex` packages in docker image via tlmgr. It worked fine till now, but the build has started failing recently with the error reported below.

How would you suggest installation of the listed packages? Maybe they included it in another bundles? How do I find them?

```
RUN tlmgr install \
    xcolor \
    colortbl \
    translator \
    varwidth \
    # most of the functionality of table packages
    tabu \
    # typesets tables with captions and notes matching width
    threeparttable \
    # provides the functionality of threeparttable to tables created using longtable
    threeparttablex \
    # lets tabular material span multiple rows
    multirow \
    floatrow \
    ctable \
    ulem \
    subfig  \
    beamer \
    environ \
    trimspaces \
    pbox
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Step 11/12 : RUN tlmgr install     xcolor     colortbl     translator     varwidth     tabu     threeparttable     threeparttablex     multirow     floatrow     ctable     ulem     subfig      beamer     environ     trimspaces     pbox
 ---> Running in fb7167663ed6

[91mTeX Live 2016 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.

[0m[91mtlmgr install: package translator not present in repository.
[0mtlmgr: package repository http://www.texlive.info/tlnet-archive/2017/04/13/tlnet (not verified: gnupg not available)
[1/16, ??:??/??:??] install: beamer [187k]

[2/16, 00:01/00:04] install: colortbl [4k]
[3/16, 00:01/00:04] install: ctable [4k]
[4/16, 00:01/00:04] install: environ [2k]
[5/16, 00:01/00:04] install: floatrow [16k]

[6/16, 00:02/00:08] install: multirow [3k]
[7/16, 00:02/00:08] install: pbox [2k]
[8/16, 00:02/00:08] install: pgf [615k]

[9/16, 00:03/00:03] install: subfig [7k]
[10/16, 00:03/00:03] install: tabu [24k]
[11/16, 00:03/00:03] install: threeparttable [6k]
[12/16, 00:04/00:04] install: threeparttablex [3k]

[13/16, 00:04/00:04] install: trimspaces [1k]
[14/16, 00:04/00:04] install: ulem [10k]
[15/16, 00:04/00:04] install: varwidth [5k]
[16/16, 00:05/00:05] install: xcolor [17k]

[91mtlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
[0mtlmgr: package log updated: /opt/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
[91mtlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
[0mService **** failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c tlmgr install     xcolor     colortbl     translator     varwidth     tabu     threeparttable     threeparttablex     multirow     floatrow     ctable     ulem     subfig      beamer     environ     trimspaces     pbox' returned a non-zero code: 1
Post stage
```

Comment: I think a while ago `translator` was distributed together with `beamer`, so it may be enough to install `beamer`.

Comment: Yes, its worked!